# How to customise the error response from spring-boot app for Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am getting http 400 error when the header exceeds the limit, I want to change it as http 431. Is there any way to modify the response?

````
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang. IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:512)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:171)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:996)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorSWorker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java. lang. Thread. run(Thread. java: 722```


how to change the response status code as http 431. Is there any way to modify the response status code and body?
````

Comment: Can you try defining a Servlet Filter and catch the exception?